# Android google maps v2 crashing on startup

Tags: java, android, crash, google-maps-android-api-2

In my android app supporting 2.2 and higher, I am trying to use the google maps api v2.

I have this so far:

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks.

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Activity_Map" >

    <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Activity_Map extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map = null;
    Geocoder coder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        coder = new Geocoder(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="sord.common.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="sord.common.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="sord.ids_connect.Activity_Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sord.ids_connect.Activity_Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sord.ids_connect.Activity_Profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="sord.ids_connect.Activity_Map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY-KEY" />
</application>
```

CRASH LOG

```
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sord.ids_connect/sord.ids_connect.Activity_Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1915)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at sord.ids_connect.Activity_Map.onCreate(Activity_Map.java:18)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     ... 11 more
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-29 22:44:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your manifest just under the `<mata-data />` and above `</application>`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The log-cat was clear to you, it identified the problem as:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

inform me if it worked, happy programming

Comment: That worked, but I used google maps api v2 before and I didn't need to add that meta tag...

Comment: ya true, but after they updated the `google play services` and `google play services for froyo` to the next rev. they added this feature.
Google Map, is one of the most unstable structure yet. so you need to keep track with all the updates regarding maps.